# How to verify Controller's ListVolumes method in Kubernetes CSI driver is working or not?

Tags: kubernetes

So we have one storage driver implemented as per Kubernetes CSI standard and recently we have implemented `ListVolumes` capability in Controller.

```
func (xyz *XYZControllerServer) ListVolumes(ctx context.Context, req *csi.ListVolumesRequest) (*csi.ListVolumesResponse, error) {
   ...
}
```

Now I am not able to see if my changes are working fine or not. 
How can we verify `ListVolumes` capability is working fine? or where we can find the logs for same?

Comment: I think [unit tests](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/unit-testing.html) from csi documentation might help to check if everything is working fine. About logs there are troubleshooting [docs](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html). Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: @jt97 Yes we have already implemented sanity test which is just for confirming that particular methods are written as per CSI standard. 
But here I want to know if `ListVolumes` method is logging details about actual volumes somewhere or not.

Comment: Take a look at implementation tips and tricks [here](https://arslan.io/2018/06/21/how-to-write-a-container-storage-interface-csi-plugin/). Specifcally this part `Have a proper logging system inside the driver. This makes it very easy to debug and observe how your driver works. I prefer using a K/V logger, such a logrus. Pairing it with a tool like humanlog will give you flexibility and easy to read logs.`

Comment: Yes...I have gone through above docs. Also we have enabled proper logging using `zap logger`. But here the question is where we can find the logs for `ListVolumes` method.
I dont see `ListVolumes` method log in controller log though.